# Alternative to window.open

Tags: javascript, dom

My question is to find an alternative for the window.open() command because it is being blocked by the ad-blocker because in my webpage it is supposed to automatically open a new window with only 1 tab. I tried the command

```
document.open()
```

with a length and width dimension to force it to open in a new window not in just as a new tab...

and it worked for me by opening a new window with only 1 tab.

I am not sure whether this just works on my device or if this is an accepted alternative.

My reasoning is that since in DOM, window is the highest level of hierarchy, typing document.open would be just as effective as window.open since document is a child node of window.

Can anybody share if this will work on other devices on major browsers like Chrome Firefox IE...?

Also is my reasoning correct?

Thanks guys!

Comment: try surrounding your code js code inside script tag wiht <!-- and --> adblocker might fail then.

Comment: It's blocked because it's *excessively* abused.  Ad-blockers allow some windows to be opened, but you'll have to check how - most likely if they occur on a click event - ie user initiated - rather than the historic open 100 popup ads when the page opens.

Comment: `window.open()` opens a new window/tab, `document.open()` clears the current tab, and reopens it for writing; wich means, your current page is gone. In this case you'd prefer a redirect (like `window.location = ...`) over `document.open()`

Comment: ad-blockers usually block `window.open()`-calls when they're not triggered by user-interaction, like a click. Often allowing a slight delay of about 50-100ms in your favor. (my experience)

Comment: sry that was wrong: popup-blocker do what I just mentioned, ad-blocker usually block either the network request, based on a defined pattern, or they remove/hide some nodes from the DOM. I'm not entirely sure wether they also block window.open-requests of undesired urls (or wether you just get an empty popup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should be using some kind of custom made popups and dialogue like**

1. http://umairj.com/27/how-to-create-simple-modal-dialogue-using-jquery/
2. http://www.jquery4u.com/windows/14-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/